# Migrating from React ES6 to TypeScript: converting (This) to type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am fairly new to TypeScript, and have been handed an ES6 based react project, and would like to Migrate over to TypeScript for a more integrated state.   Anything following a (this.) seems to break with error (Property "foo" does not exist on Type "bar")

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
class Clock extends Component {
    constructor(props: {}) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            date: new Date()
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.timerId = setInterval(
            () => this.tick(), 500
        );
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.timerId);
    }

    tick() {
        this.setState({
            date: new Date()
        });
    }

    render() {
        const options = { hour24: false };

        return (
            <div className="clockDesign">{this.state.date.toLocaleString('en-US', options)}</div>
        );
    }
}

export default Clock;
```

My question is this. How would I go about converting the inline definitions to types within my class statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the fields of your class before assigning them. For example:

```
class Clock extends Component {

    private state: { date: Date }

    constructor(props: {}) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            date: new Date()
        };
    }

    // ...
}
```

Or if `state` is supposed to be inherited from `Component`, then you might have some problems with your typings (`npm install @typings/react`).

Comment: Would this also apply to the (this.timerId) statements? I should have been more clear in my question, but the date was a secondary issue as well

Comment: Yes, there you would use `private timerId: number` (or `public` depending on your case)

Comment: Thank you very much, testing now. I am on hold for accepting.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick. I had to switch them all to public, to prevent an incorrect extension error.

Answer (score 1):

Use **interfaces** (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html):

```
interface Props = {

};

interface State = {
  date: Date;
}

class Clock extends Component<Props, State> {
  private timerId: any;

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      date: new Date()
    };
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add correct generic arguments and you need to define the class properties. See comments.

import * as React from 'react';

```
interface IProps { }
interface IState {
    date: Date;
}

class Clock extends React.Component<IProps, IState> { //You need to define both props and state
    constructor(props: {}) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            date: new Date()
        };
    }

    timerId: any; //Props needs to be defined;
    componentDidMount() {
        this.timerId = setInterval(
            () => this.tick(), 500
        );
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.timerId);
    }

    tick() {
        this.setState({
            date: new Date()
        });
    }

    render() {
        const options = { hour24: false };

        return (
            <div className="clockDesign"> {this.state.date.toLocaleString('en-US', options)} </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Clock;
```